# SQL select with complex insert

Tags: mysql

I am trying to concatenate 2 tables into 1 table with 1 mysql command.  I also want to concatenate a file path into one path in the new table.  Any information would be helpful.  Thank you.

Something like this :

```
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (Location) SELECT "A.Loc_Path B._FilePath" FROM Table2 A INNER JOIN table1 B ON A._Loc_ID = B._Loc_ID
```

I would like to take Table 1 & 2 and create Table 3

Table 1

```
| ID | _FilePath        | _Loc_ID |
| 1  | 001\yay\txt.html |    1    | 
| 1  | 002\yay\txt.php  |    2    |
```

Table 2

```
| _Loc_ID | Loc_Path           |
|    1    | D:\documents\test\ |
|    2    | C:\Temp\test\      |
```

Table 3

```
|  Id  | Location                           |
|   1  | D:\documents\test\001\yay\txt.html |
|   2  | C:\Temp\test\002\yay\txt.php       |
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use concat

```
INSERT INTO table3 (Location) SELECT concat (A.Loc_Path , B._FilePath)  
FROM Table2 A INNER JOIN table1 B ON A._Loc_ID = B._Loc_ID
```

Comment: Hey, i'm curious, isnt it supposed to be `INSERT INTO table3(Location) VALUES (XXX)` where XXX is the concatenation result ? I mean as the doc says... If you don't mind explaining :-)

Comment: @Enissay please explain better your comment . I don't understand  .. you need a better explanation of concat?

Comment: No, the `VALUES` keyword position confuses me; Also using the `INSERT... SELECT ` syntax, it should be `INSERT INTO table3(Location) SELECT...` xD

Comment: Well, @Nir Levy came up with the same solution, that made me think it was some alternative form to do so as I'm trying to re-build my rusty sql knowledge xD ; Thks <3 [upvoted]

Answer (score 2):

what you need is to use the [concat function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to concatenate the two columns:

```
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (Location) SELECT CONCAT(A.Loc_Path, B._FilePath) FROM 
  Table2 A INNER JOIN table1 B ON A._Loc_ID = B._Loc_ID
```